# javascript changing style attribute breaks events chain?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html:

```
<span style="display:none" id="progressBar">HELLO</span>        
<span id="statusPremium">NULL</span>
<span id="statusLink">NULL</span>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="12345" onchange="document.getElementById('statusPremium').innerHTML='ONCHANGE';document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display='block';"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('statusLink').innerHTML='ONCLICK';">CLICK</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I enter input item then editing it and then click link. I expect both text ie. ONCHANGE ONCLICK appears. However I can see only ONCHANGE.
If I remove:

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display='block';
```

the behaviour is as I expected. But if then I remove all table, tr and td tags there is again only ONCHANGE.
Could please some enlighten me why it works that way?

Comment: Why would you want to use those long ugly inline event handlers anyway? javascript files exist for a reason

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fmd8xc5q/

Comment: @andrew Sorry but it's only an exceprt from a real code which involved jsf and much more tags. I tried to keep it concise to depict the issue. But I would appreciate if you suggest a cleaner version.

I can't agree that your example works Martin Gottweis as it presents the same symptom which troubled me. "Onchange" works always fine. But "onclick" only when "onchange" didn't set "display" property to "block".